# Hosting a Private AppStore (for iOS) on SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, hyperlink, app

I need to distribute apps for my company from SharePoint online platform.

The problem is that when I put on the SharePoint online platform a link like:

```
<a href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=URL/APP.plist">Install App »</a>
```

The system erase it leaving just an empty "a" tag like:

```
<a>Install App »</a>
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Is there any other way to do that without involving external machines?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is via a Content Editor Web Part, then the answer would be to put the anchor ref in a text file and put in a document library. Then using the content editor, link to the text file (WP Properties) and the anchor will display unchanged.